BulkWriteException: Immutable Field '_id' Altered Error
I'm encountering an issue with MongoDB when performing a bulk write operation. The error message I’m receiving is:
`MongoBulkWriteException`1: A bulk write operation resulted in one or more errors. WriteErrors: [ { Category : "Uncategorized", Code : 66, Message : "After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: ObjectId('66cae1a9d300b4e662d5c2ee')" } ]
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl<TDocument>.BulkWriteAsync(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable<WriteModel<TDocument>> requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

MongoWriteException: A write operation resulted in an error. WriteError: { Category : "Uncategorized", Code : 66, Message : "After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: ObjectId('66cae1a9d300b4e662d5c2ee')" }
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase<TDocument>.ReplaceOneAsync(FilterDefinition<TDocument> filter, TDocument replacement, ReplaceOptions options, Func<IEnumerable<WriteModel<TDocument>>, BulkWriteOptions, Task<BulkWriteResult<TDocument>>> bulkWriteAsync)`

Context:
I'm using MongoDB .NET Driver for bulk write operations.
The error occurs during a ReplaceOneAsync operation.
It seems to be related to an attempt to update the _id field, which should be immutable.
Here’s the code for the repository where the issue is happening:
`using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using DataAccess.Interfaces;
using DataAccess.Models;

namespace DataAccess.Repositories
{
    public class MongoConfigurationRepository : IConfigurationRepository
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<ConfigurationRecord> _collection;

        public MongoConfigurationRepository(string connectionString, string databaseName, string collectionName)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
            _collection = database.GetCollection<ConfigurationRecord>(collectionName);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<ConfigurationRecord>> GetActiveConfigurationsAsync(string applicationName)
        {
            var filter = Builders<ConfigurationRecord>.Filter.And(
                Builders<ConfigurationRecord>.Filter.Eq(r => r.ApplicationName, applicationName),
                Builders<ConfigurationRecord>.Filter.Eq(r => r.IsActive, true)
            );

            var asd = _collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

            return await _collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<ConfigurationRecord> GetConfigurationAsync(ObjectId id)
        {
            var filter = Builders<ConfigurationRecord>.Filter.Eq(r => r.Id, id);

            return await _collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public async Task AddOrUpdateConfigurationAsync(ConfigurationRecord record)
        {
            if (record.Id == ObjectId.Empty)
            {
                record.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
            }

            var filter = Builders<ConfigurationRecord>.Filter.And(
                Builders<ConfigurationRecord>.Filter.Eq(r => r.ApplicationName, record.ApplicationName),
                Builders<ConfigurationRecord>.Filter.Eq(r => r.Name, record.Name)
            );

            await _collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, record, new ReplaceOptions { IsUpsert = true });
        }

        public async Task DeleteConfigurationAsync(ObjectId id)
        {
            var filter = Builders<ConfigurationRecord>.Filter.Eq(r => r.Id, id);

            await _collection.DeleteOneAsync(filter);
        }
    }
}
`

What could be causing this issue where it seems like the _id field is being altered?
How can I ensure that _id remains unchanged during update operations?
I've double-checked my code and confirmed that I’m not explicitly trying to modify the _id field. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
I attempted to perform a bulk write operation using ReplaceOneAsync to either update an existing record or insert a new one if it doesn't exist.
